# Where to find the skybox package in Unity5?

Tags: unity-game-engine, skybox

I'm fairly new to Unity and I'm following a tutorial on adding skybox to my scene. In the tutorial they are using Unity4 and they do Assets>Import Package>Skybox but I do not see this option in Unity 5. Anyone know where it's located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Window->Lighting menu to apply a skybox material to your scene.

To override for a specific Camera add a Component->Rendering->Skybox to the Camera GameObject.

See: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Skybox.html

For skybox materials you can go to the Asset Store and download the free [Standard Assets for 4.6](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21064) from Unity. There should be some other free skyboxes on the Asset store are well, or you can download from the web then create a new material in Unity 5 and select the Skybox shader (supports 6 sides, cube map, procedural) and set the textures.

Comment: Very helpful information about Unity's new Skybox system, however this doesn't answer the OP's question, which I think is asking how to import the default skyboxes in Unity 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you had downloaded any version of Unity prior to Unity 5-

Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Standard Packages` and double-click on the `Skyboxes` file.

But you need fix the alpha in the textures, go to the project panel `"/Standard Assets/Skyboxes/"` in the hierarchy and then select one skybox. Click the "[fix now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS8qr.jpg)" buttons in the inspector. Do this for all skyboxes.